# Cartopy is unable to download data behind proxy despite proxies being set in os.environ

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3, cartopy

I am using Python 3.5 and cartopy 0.17.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

When I try and execute this I am presented with a 502 Bad Gateway Error as the library is attempting to download Natural Earth datasets:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cartopy/io/__init__.py", line 260
warnings.warn('Downloading: {}'.format(url), DownloadWarning)
DownloadWarning: Downloading: http://naciscdn.org/naturaleart/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1253, in connect super().connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 853, in connect self._tunnel()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 832, in _tunnel message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cartopy/io/shapereader.py", line 359, in natural_earth
return ne_downloader.path(format_dict)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1256, in do_open raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway>
```

The 502 code indicated a proxy error however I have set my proxies in os.environ using the following keys and I still get the same error:

```
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY']= 'proxyaddress:port'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']= 'proxyaddress:port'
```

How do I tell urllib3 via cartopy to use the proxy information in the Python environment? Is there something else which could be causing this error?

Note: I am following the tutorial located on the official documentation [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/intro.html)

Comment: Try setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` instead of (or in addition to) the uppercase variants. The case conventions for those environment variables are weird.

Comment: @user2357112 I've tried the lower case versions and still get the same error unfortunately